# Hibernate MySQL Cant create table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im learning hibernate and i got stuck at the very beginning. So the problem is that my app cant auto-create table. Here goes all the code:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>   
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="azaro.test.hibernate.UserDetails" />    
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateTest.java

```
package azaro.test.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

UserDetails.java

```
package azaro.test.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

And the console output:

```
Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName, userId) values (?, ?)
Sep 23, 2013 6:34:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Sep 23, 2013 6:34:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at azaro.test.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:23)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 14 more
```

If  you need more info, feel free to ask.

Comment: did you create the schema ? i faced this kind of problem when hibernate didn't create the db, change to <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">update</property>, try to run first "create database hibernatedb" and then run your code..

Comment: Schema is created, the thing is if i create the table in that db by myself my app will put object in it. Tried update also, same result.

Comment: then try to modify your entity, add table name to your entity annotation, and also add the rest of the columns (@Column) of your fields..

Comment: Nothing changed:
@Table(name="UserDetails", schema="hibernatedb"), @Column(name="ID", unique=true), @Column(name="Name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ddl that is generated using

```
SchemaExport(cfg).create(true, true);
```

Using this you will know the ddl and can analyze better. Also if schema is already updated. Set hbm2ddl.auto to 'create-drop'

Comment: All the same exceptions.

Comment: AnnotationConfiguration() didnt help and its deprecated :(

Comment: can you try to check out schema export options and analyze the ddl script which hibernate is using to create the schema. That is add the following line to get the ddl in your console'
new SchemaExport(cfg).create(true, true);

Comment: Also if schema is already created I suppose you need to change it 'create-drop' so that hibernate drops previous schema and creates again

Comment: Wow man, it helped! I have added your line after configuration.configure(); and now its working! ddl is -  
drop table if exists hibernatedb.UserDetails

    create table hibernatedb.UserDetails (
        ID integer not null,
        Name varchar(255),
        primary key (ID)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: But its droping table before creating, how can i keep the table and just add new rows?

Comment: set the property hbm2ddl.auto as validate once the schema is created

Comment: Nah, SchemaExport(cfg).create(true, true); This line is droping the table before creation.

Comment: You will have to call this create method only if the schema is not existing. So there has to be some method which will help us identify if schema is already created. You will have to find that in Hibernate apis

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the `cfg.xml` file. Change hbm2**dll** to hbm2**ddl** in

```
"hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create
```

Then life will be beautiful again.
I know this because I made the same mistake and spent some hours to
figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

add in configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) update and use @Column annotation to create column in databse

Answer (score 0):

The 'SQLGrammarException' exception means the wrong syntax has written while the configuration of dialect.

```
Sep 23, 2013 6:34:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'hibernatedb.userdetails' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer:

- The correct dialect entry is: [<property name="hibernate.dialect">]
  ~~~~~~~~~~
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
  ~~~~~~~~~

- The given is found from your XML file. [<property name="dialect">]
  ~~~~~~~~~
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="azaro.test.hibernate.UserDetails" />    
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~

Root Cause: The hibernate property should start with the 'hibernate.' prefix!

In this case, your code contains the property with the "dialect" prefix and this is wrong. Replace it with the "hibernate.dialect".


- Sarfaraz
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

MySQL5Dialact refers to the MyISAM storage type and the MySQL5InnoDBDialect the InnoDB (newer) type.

Comment: Changing dialect didnt help :(

Answer (score -2):

do not initiate the user to null and configure hbm2ddl as create-drop, the code will execute with the result as follows:

Hibernate: insert into USER_DETAILS (Address, description, joinedDate, userName, userId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select userdetail0_.userId as userId1_0_0_, userdetail0_.Address as Address2_0_0_, userdetail0_.description as descript3_0_0_, userdetail0_.joinedDate as joinedDa4_0_0_, userdetail0_.userName as userName5_0_0_ from USER_DETAILS userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.userId=?

user name retreived isfirst user